# Execution time display in C++: cin/scanf/getchar_unlocked()

Tags: c++, execution-time

I'm working on a project to show that `std::cin` is slower in taking input as compared to `scanf` which in turn will be slower than taking input via self written functions using `getchar/getchar_unlocked()` and so on.

I want to record and print the execution time in each case but I don't know how to apply time and chrono etc header files.
I'll be reading a bulk of input values from stdin and want to display the execution time in each case.

Please tell me how to deal with time in this with a short example.

Comment: look up `gettimeofday()` from `sys/time.h`.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like

```
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

some_long_running_operation();

auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

std::cout << "Operation took " <<
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() <<
    " microseconds\n";
```

(More or less taken verbatim [from this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono), and its sub-pages. More specifically from the second example for the [`std::chrono::time_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) reference, just changed the clock used.)

What the code does is get the current time from the high-resolution clock as start time, perform the operation that is to be times, and then get the end time. It then displays the difference in microseconds.

Comment: Can you please tell how to use/ when and how to call these functions in my program?

Comment: @CPPCoder But that's it, nothing more needed. The `some_long_running_operation()` call in my example code is the code you want to time.

Comment: I was already writing when you added this answer :)). You won this time

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <time.h>
clock_t t;
void startTimer() {
    t = clock();
}
void stopTimer() {
    t = clock() - t;
    printf("It took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n", t, ((float)t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

And then call these two methods as you wish.

OR

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct timeval t1, t2;
struct timezone tz;

void startTimer()
{
    gettimeofday(&t1, &tz);
}

void stopTimer()
{
    gettimeofday(&t2, &tz);
        cout<<"It took "<< t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec <<" seconds and "<< t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec<<" microseconds"<<endl;;
}

// call "startTimer()" to start timer
// call "stopTimer()" to stop timer and print total time in microseconds.
```

Comment: Do you mean I should call these as startTimer() /* Then take input using say cin */ stopTimer() ?

Comment: @CPPCoder yes exactly

Comment: Your program is working but it's always showing zero seconds. Can I have better precision say in nanoseconds. Thanks